# Searching for multiple values in a nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection:

```
{
 _id: 1,
 docs: [{
          name: file1,
          labels: [label1, label2, label3, label4]
        },{
          name: file2,
          labels: [label3, label4]
        },{
          name: file3,
          labels: [label1, label3, label4]
        }]
 }
```

When a user searches for labels, I need to get all the docs that have those labels.

So if a user searches for "label1" and "label3", I need to get "file1" and "file3". At the moment I have the following code:

```
    var collection = db.collection(req.user.username);

    collection.aggregate([
      // Unwind each array
      { "$unwind": "$docs" },
      { "$unwind": "$docs.labels" },

      // Filter just the matching elements
      {
          "$match": {
              "docs.labels": { "$all": ["label1", "label3"] }
          }
      }
    ]).toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.send(items);
    });
```

This works fine if I only search for "label1" or "label3", but not the two together. Can you please help me with this, since I haven't found an answer that works myself.

Comment: What is your mongod version?

Comment: Why you didn't use `mongoose`  module?

Comment: @Styvane my mongo is version 3.2.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can efficiently do this by [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)ing your documents in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) stage.

```
let inputLabels = ["label1", "label3"];

collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "docs.labels": { "$all": inputLabels }}}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "docs": { 
            "$filter": { 
                "input": "$docs", 
                "as": "doc", 
                "cond": { "$setIsSubset": [ inputLabels, "$$doc.labels" ] }
            }
        }
    }}
])]).toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.send(items);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I tried using `$project` and `$filter` myself, but I wasn't able to get the desired result as I didn't fully understand it.